# Why are the cells the smallest unit of life?

Tags: cell-biology, life, eukaryotic-cells

Please Tell me why the cells are called the smallest unit of life. According to me I know that they are called so because they are smallest entity which is alive that is they show the properties of life on their own but if we divide them then the life will be destroyed. If that's the case so why they need to stay in a body why they can't be alone. I want to ask that if we separate a human cell from its body then can the cell be alive. If there is any better explanation that can explain why are the cells called the smallest unit of life please tell

Comment: Lots of cells exist that don't need to be in a body.  Bacteria, protozoa, single-celled algae, and many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An individual living being**, whose material body consists of one or more cells, **is the unit of life.** The cells are not the units of life, but the units of the material body.

*Multicellularity* leads to *specialization* leads to *dependence* leads to *loss of autonomous existence of an individual cell*.